# Can I change the appearance of a single hyperlink in PowerPoint 2010?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

Can I change the appearance of a single hyperlink in PowerPoint 2010? I don't want to change all the theme's hyperlinks.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, you can change the font, size etc. but not the colour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

You can change pretty much everything (size, case, spacing, style, shadows etc.) except the color.

The only way to change color will affect other links too, cause it's a theme change. Copying from word won't work either.

Answer (score 4):

While you can't change the formatting of text you've applied a hyperlink to, you can apply the hyperlink to the text BOX (click in the text then press ESC to select the box) that contains the text.  Or if you want to apply the link to only a portion of the text within a text box, you can draw a rectangle that covers the area you want to turn into a link, apply the link to the rectangle, then give it no outline, any color fill but make the fill 99 or 100% transparent.

Comment: That's a nice workaround, especially if converting to PDF maintains the links.

Comment: That will depend on the platform and conversion tool.  On Windows, PPT's own File | Save As | PDF feature will preserve the links either way.  On Mac, no links are preserved, but Adobe Reader/et al defaults to recognizing text that *looks* like a URL and converting it to live links.  That wouldn't work for links applied to shapes, but if the shape also had text with the URL in it, the text would be treated as a link in the PDF (*IF* the user has Reader set to do so).

Answer (score 1):

You can duplicate the slide master, change the color theme/scheme for the second slide master, then apply that layout to the individual slide that needs a new hyperlink color.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).